# Need to produce an Issue - "This file came from another computer"

Tags: windows-7, security

I need to reproduce this issue for some particular reason.

[image]

The thing is I'm struggling to get the message to appear on a folder:

> Security : This File came from another computer and might be blocked
>   to help protect this computer.

I tried downloading and extracting a RAR File (With a folder present in it, but that didn’t work)
Any ideas how I can get this message to appear on a folder?

It would be useful if someone can host a harmless folder for me to download. That way I’m hoping the source is identified and unknown & this message will appear.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where this message comes from, but I would say it comes from NTFS security settings. That means a file has to be copied over the network directly so it can retain the NTFS security settings. Zipping the file removes those rights. This is however an assumption, but may help you find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a folder can indeed have alternate data streams, the message you want won’t appear.

You can try this yourself. Create a file with the following contents, named `internet.ini` or whatever:

```
[ZoneTransfer]
ZoneId=3
```

Then, create a regular file, like a Word document and execute the following command in a Command Prompt:

```
type internet.ini > test.docx:Zone.Identifier
```

The file will then have that hint and button. Instead of `test.docx`, a folder could be used. However, the hint will not appear in that case.

[More documentation on ADS and Zone.Identifier](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2013/03/24/alternate-data-streams-in-ntfs.aspx)